# Axios POST request sending but not being recieved

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, axios

I know this has been asked before but any solutions I've tried have failed to get results so far. I'm new to Axios and I'm trying to test sending a POST request, and it seems like the request is indeed sent, but it never ends up actually being received, despite showing a 200 OK status code. I've been troubleshooting a while, but no amount of changing headers or fiddling with the server seems to have changed anything.

#### Sending Request

```js
handleSubmit(event){
        event.preventDefault();

        var myObj = {
            email: this.state.userEmail,
            password: this.state.userPassword,
            failedLogin: this.state.failedLogin
        }

        // validate login
        axios.post("/login", myObj)
        .then(function(response){
            console.log(response.data.test);
        })
        .catch(function (error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    }
```

#### Receiving Request

The alert with "receive" is never executed.

```js
userRoutes.route("/login").post((req, res) => {
    console.log("sent");
    res.send({test: "test"})
});
```

And my requests/responses and console:

[request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBMpu.png)

[response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NkPJM.png)

[console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeP4K.png)

Comment: Three questions... 1) What version of Axios are you using? 2) Why are you manually setting the content-type header? 3) What is `alert()` meant to be? It's not a thing in Node.JS

Comment: Your Express route looks wrong. Typically it's just something like `userRoutes.route("/login").post(...)`. See https://expressjs.com/en/guide/routing.html

Comment: Ok so
1.) I'm currently using Axios 1.2.1
2.) The manual setting of the header is just a remnant of another solution I've tried, works the same with or without it, but I'd imagine I can just leave it out.
3.) That was just a dumb mistake on my part lol, I forgot it does nothing in Node.

Comment: Despite stripping my code to just
`userRoutes.route("/login").post((req, res) => {
    console.log("sent");
    res.send({test: "test"})
});`

things still seem to be having trouble. I'm PRETTY sure i'm following all the intended syntax still no good. Might be an issue with server configuration?

Comment: Your Axios request was probably ok, it was your Express route that was incorrect. There's not really enough context here. Are your front-end and backend separate apps or is Express also serving your front-end? If separate, have you configured `cors()` in your Express app or are you using a proxy? How is `userRoutes` defined? How is it integrated into your Express app?

Comment: Yeah, you need to make sure that the code in your handler is being called when you post with something other than axios before you call this an axios error. Even if your handler code as shown is right, another piece of middleware or another route can easily be handling that path instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure enough, as @Phil and @trognanders suggested, the problem was because my Express middleware was configured incorrectly, hence not an Axios problem.

Answer (score -1):

Axios signature for post is `axios.post(url[, data[, config]])`. So your object should be written as 3rd parameter. Also, your post url must be complete. Otherwise you will get invalid url error.

Sending Request

```
axios
 .post("http://localhost:3000/login", null, yourObj)
 .then((res) => {
   console.log(res.data.test);
   // Result: test
 })
 .catch((err) => console.log(err));
```

Receiving Request

```
app.post("/login", (req, res) => {
  res.status(200).json({ test: "test" });
});
```

Comment: This is just incorrect. The request body / data goes in the 2nd parameter, not the 3rd